# How do I install clang-format without root privileges and without installing LLVM?

Tags: clang-format

I have `clang-format version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)` in my `~/bin` folder on a Fedora machine with no root privileges. It works, but it is very old and I'd like to upgrade. I just want the clang-format tool, so I would like to avoid going through the full installation process for LLVM or clang if I can avoid it. I assume I can avoid it, since my old `clang-format` works without either of those installed. I don't remember how clang-format got in my `~/bin` directory, and I can't figure out how to update it.

The first thing I tried was following [this post](https://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-install-clang-format-and-formatting-objective-c-files/) which said I should be able to download a prebuilt binary from [this page](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) (I tried http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/clang+llvm-6.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-Fedora27.tar.xz), then just set up a symlink to `bin/clang-format`. This did not work for me. When I type `/path/to/bin/clang-format --help` I get the error `error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

The next thing I tried is downloading the clang source code and compiling that with

```
mkdir build && cd build && CC=$(which gcc) CXX=$(which g++) cmake ..
```

but when I did I got the error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (message):
  llvm-config not found -- LLVM_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
```

Which I guess means I'd need to install the LLVM to go this route?

Any help getting an updated clang-format (vesion 5.0 at minimum) without root access would be appreciated. Bonus points for minimal installation (i.e. no clang or llvm).

## === EDIT ===

By downloading a bunch of different versions of prebuilt binaries, I've discovered that older versions (<4.0) have `clang-format`s that work out of the box, but at 4.0 and up give the same error about `libtinfo`. I guess that means I'll have to live with older versions unless I want to go through a painful installation process.

Answer (score 0):

When you download llvm 6.0, make sure the directory structure is as follows:

> llvm
>    |-->tools
>      |----->clang
>               |----> tools
>                        |----> extra
>
> If you just want to build `clang-format`, then you can `cd` into

`llvm-build-dir/tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-format` and then execute `make -j8 all`

later you can make a symbolic link in your `/bin` folder

Comment: Thanks! However, when I download either the llvm or clang source code I don't see a directory structure like that. In `llvm-6.0.0.src` the results of `find . -name '*clang-format*'` are `./test/.clang-format` and `./.clang-format`. The same command in the clang source code shows a `tools/clang-format` directory, but `make` doesn't work there since there's no makefile. What's the link to the source files where you see that directory structure?

Comment: @BenLindsay : Are you doing a grep in your llvm build directory? And llvm,clang and clang-extra are three different repositories

Comment: I ran that `find` command in the root directory of 3 different source downloads. The 3 downloads I tried are from [the LLVM download page](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). Those 3 downloads are 1) is the [LLVM Source Code](http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/llvm-6.0.0.src.tar.xz), 2) the [Clang Source Code](http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/cfe-6.0.0.src.tar.xz), and 3) the [clang-tools-extra source code](http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/clang-tools-extra-6.0.0.src.tar.xz). I didn't find that directory structure in any of them. What source download should I be looking in?

Comment: I'm still really curious to hear what source code you found that directory structure in. Could you please post a link or something?

Comment: You have to execute `find` command in the build directory structure that is created through `cmake`, NOT in the source code directory.

Comment: This is a bit different from what you first said...you made it sound like that directory structure should be there when you download it. If you look at my actual question, you'll see that cmake didn't work for me in the first place. If you want to actually help me then tell me 1) what link to download 2) what build command to run and where to run it, and 3) where clang-format will be when it's done. I managed to get cmake working on llvm-6.0.0 on a different machine with the same command I mentioned in my question, and I still don't see any directory structure like you mentioned